# Gradle Project Sync Fails after Kotlin Plugin Update

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

After I updated to the newest plugin for kotlin I get this build error in my project

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method 1.8() for arguments [1.8] on object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptionsImpl.
```

My gradle is,

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        def nav_version = "2.1.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Other file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8" JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.barrechat191"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
// To inline the bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into
// bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. (e.g. navArgs)
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"
    def nav_version = "2.1.0"
    def paging_version = "2.1.1"

    implementation 'com.luckycatlabs:SunriseSunsetCalculator:1.2'

    //Page Lib implementation and RecyclerView
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$paging_version"
    // For Kotlin use paging-runtime-ktx
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    //Implement Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    //Implement constraintLayout
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternatively - just ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // For Kotlin use lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx
    // alternatively - just LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternatively - Lifecycles only (no ViewModel or LiveData). Some UI
    //     AndroidX libraries use this lightweight import for Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"


    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0'


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Kotlin Coroutine support for ViewModel
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0-alpha01'
    //Coroutine support for LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0-alpha01'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-alpha01'

    //Dependency Injection
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.25.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.2'

    //*******************************************
    //*************  A   W   S ******************
    //*******************************************

    // Mobile Client for initializing the SDK
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:@aar') { transitive = true }

    // Cognito UserPools for SignIn
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0'
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:@aar') { transitive = true }

    // Sign in UI Library
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0'
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:@aar') { transitive = true }


    //******************************************
    //************  GOOGLE MAPS ****************
    //******************************************
    implementation name: 'maps-sdk-3.0.0-beta', ext: 'aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'


    //******************************************
    //**************** ROOM ********************
    //******************************************

    def room_version = "2.2.3"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

    /**
     *
     * TESTING ->
     *
     */
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'

    implementation "com.github.drfonfon:android-kotlin-geohash:1.0"

}
```

Not sure what could be going wrong here.  Everything worked fine until recent upgrade.  Any ideas as to how to fix this issue?

I've tried going through and making sure everything was in sync and the correct version.  But it still throws the same build error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
android {
    ...
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    ...
}
```

looks a bit strange

jvmTarget = "1.8" **JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8**

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the job!  I wonder why it built successfully before for a few months up until this most recent update.

Comment: Glad to hear that!